# distributing eclipse build, debug, and external tool configurations to my coworkers

Tags: eclipse, maven

I'm building some *fancy* build debug and external tool configs for an eclipse project so the build button will build locally, the debug button will debug remotely, and the external tool button** will deploy to a test box.

I find these really useful and would like a way to package them up and distribute them to coworkers. I dont want to push the whole project configuration on people because everyone has different project configurations.

ps: any background on how tasks are stored and how to import them would also be well appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like you might get a lot of benefit out of TeamCity (www.jetbrains.com/teamcity).  It is a continuous integration server with a feature called Remote Run.  This allows you to remotely run your build/test suite with changes from your local Eclipse environment.  If and only if the build/test is successful, your files will be committed to version control.

Answer (score 2):

You can mark a configuration as shared and it put it into your project as a file. You can then add that file to source control and it will appear in other developers' environments. On the Common tab, you switch from Local file to Shared file. I think this only works if you've got the .project and other configuration files under source control.

I just noticed that you're using maven, so you probably don't have the .project under source control. You may have to get each developer to manually add the launch file into their project. I don't know.